# How can i rewrite the following code with switchmap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Hi I have a small code snippet using rxjs library as follows. It is working fine . However I would like to re write it using switchmap . I tried all option however i am getting an error . was wondering if someone could help me out .

```
this.campaignControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
(value) => {
    this.flightsService.getUnpaginatedFlightsWithinRange(
          {
                 campaignId : value,
                 jobStatuses: this.flightStatusIds,
                 rangeStartDate: 
                 (this.rangeControl.value[0]).toISOString(),
                 rangeEndDate: (this.rangeControl.value[1]).toISOString()
          }
).subscribe(
      (flightsUnpaginated) => {
             this.flights = flightsUnpaginated;
            }
         );
   }
);
```

thank you

Comment: Please post what you tried, post the exact and complete error you got, and indent your code properly so that we (and you) can read it

Comment: i changed the indent ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```js
this.campaignControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap(value => this.flightsService.getUnpaginatedFlightsWithinRange({
    campaignId : value,
    jobStatuses: this.flightStatusIds,
    rangeStartDate: (this.rangeControl.value[0]).toISOString(),
    rangeEndDate: (this.rangeControl.value[1]).toISOString()
  }),
  tap(flightsUnpaginated => this.flights = flightsUnpaginated)
).subscribe();
```

Comment: thank you so much . i was also trying the same thing how ever was getting an error . brilliant